# AWS Amplify Cognito Auth with multiple registration email templates

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, email-templates

I am attempting to setup AWS Amplify authentication, but I would like two user types.

Requirements:

1. System should allow userTypeOne and userTypeTwo to register.
2. User selects userType by using a radio button
3. Once registered userType will receive an templated email unique to their userType
4. The two userTypes are linked, think student and teacher
5. The registration email template must be able to support additional custom templated values `{myCustomParam}`

Questions

1. Has anyone tried to use AWS Amplify to setup a two user type registration flow?
2. Does anyone know how to trigger a different registration template based on the user type?
3. Can additional custom templated values be included in the registration email?
4. If so how does one pass these parameters to the template?

These are the questions I am trying to answer, if you could share what you have that would be great. I will continue to accumulate the information and share it here.

Comment: Any updates to share? I have found several options and need to decide which route to take pretty soon here.

Comment: No updates, haven't had the time to come back to this. I am currently in high level discussions with some architects over at AND.digital. Will come back and update this when I have a solution

Comment: Okay, sounds good. :thumbsup: